# How to invert texture images

Tags: texturing

I have model and texture many buildings.

[image]

[image]

Im making a night screen and all im doing is saving the image and opening the image paying with photoshop hue and contrast making the night view

[image]

Then accessing the image. Is there any quick or way to make the image night view image other than jumping to photoshop and blender. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX3Cw.png)[image]

[image]

SO here i have used gamma along with color ramp to create the mask for windows to provide it a reddis color. You can use this setup and improvise some to get the result. The base

[image]

Now you can group these nodes to create a group ny CTRL+G and just use it everywhere! Just add this node and feed the image and you will be done for every textures!

https://www21.zippyshare.com/v/kR7bPQxd/file.html

Comment: I have attach a blend file can you plz show how it works

Comment: i have edited the comment. let me know if it helped

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that is need but i have more than 100 building i have select every building and connect the node. Any quick way.

Comment: check out the answer again! cheers

Comment: can you plz send me the file